# Is NetPeerTcpBinding available on Mono?

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

I'd like to know whether Mono's implementation of WCF already implements NetPeerTcpBinding.

Anyone is using it? Some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See for yourself.](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/NetPeerTcpBinding.cs?view=markup)  It does not appear to be near completion.

Answer (score 1):

[NetPeerTcpBinding is part of Milestone 5](http://mono-project.com/WCF) of WCF on Mono, currently Mono is at Milestone 1.

Comment: It will take some time then... :-P